# Identifying why Google Play Services is hogging background data

Tags: google-play-services, data-monitoring, background-data

My biggest data usage is Google Play Services background data.

Google Play Services is used by many other apps, hiding which app is actually responsible for the data usage.  This also means you can't block background data for this app, because it will have side effects like preventing Google Hangouts from working.

How do I identify which apps are actually responsible for this data usage?

Comment: Which version of Android are you running ?

Comment: @CzarMatt CM11 Android 4.4.4